# Async function fails with no errors inside sync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next code:

```
function validator(User) {
    (async () => await saveData({ User }))();
    // some other code
}

async function saveData({ User }) {
   const res = await PGclient.query(
    `
    INSERT INTO some_table (user)
    VALUES ($1)
  `,
    [User],
  );
  return res;
}
```

But nothing is inserted in to table. After call 'await PGclient.query', code execution jumps to main function 'validator' and doesn't hits 'return res' also.

Comment: Why do you wrap it in another object to immediately unwrap it again?

Comment: Updated topic. How then I can call anyc function inside sync?

Comment: async function validator(User) {
    const res =  await saveData({ User }); 
    return res;
}

Comment: It's because validator function also returns an async function. 
There is no point to wrap it again. hope it helped you (:

Comment: @BhaskarJoshi `validator` function should be an ASYNC to call `await saveData()`

Comment: I can't make validator async, that is the trick

Comment: hvn't seen that , edited now

Comment: Can you try saveData({ User }).then((res) => console.log(res)).

Comment: Try to call `saveData({User}).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(e => console.log('ERROR: ', e))`

Comment: the same, just continue executing in main function